# polynomial maximum / minimum problem [precalculus]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would be the minimum dimensions of a rectangular box with the smallest surface area that has a volume of 288 and has a width 3 times its length.

$$V = lwh$$

$$l = 3w$$

so $V = 3w^2 \cdot h$ and thus $h = \frac{3w^2}{V}$

$$\text{Total surface area} = (2wh) + (2lw) + (2lh)$$
substitute h into the equation and ...

$$\frac{576}W + 6W^2 + \frac{576}{3W}$$

I used a graphing calculator to come up with $[w = width] \frac{576}W + 6W^2 + \frac{576}{3W}$ which gives $\approx 1.65$ as the minimum. However, I feel this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have $V= lwh$ with $w= 3l$ (do check this!), so $V= 3l^2h$.

Surface area $S = 2wh + 2lw + 2lh= 6lh + 6l^2 + 2lh = 8lh+6l^2$

So $S= 4lh + 4lh + 6l^2$ is the sum of positive terms, whose product is a constant $\frac{32}{3} V^2$.  Hence this sum is minimised when all the terms are the same, viz. $4lh=6l^2$ or when $l = \frac23 h$.

Hence $V = \frac43 h^3$ and you can solve for $h = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3V}{4}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3\cdot 288}{4}}=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, that should be $h = V/3w^2$, shouldn't it?  Also, if the width is 3 times its length, doesn't that mean that $w = 3l$, not $l = 3w$?  After that, one substitutes that back into the formula to get surface area  $2(576/w + w^2/3 + 288/w) = (4*288/w + 2*w^2/6)$ and then one can use A.M.-G.M. with 6 terms to get a minimal surface area of 288 when $w = 12$.  In that case, l would be 4 and h would be 6.

Comment: A primer on $\LaTeX$ is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  When you write V/3w^2, please supply parentheses.  Here it is clear you mean $V/(3w^2)$, not $(V/3)w^2$ but people often mean the other.  Even better, stack the fraction \frac V{3w^2} gives $\frac V{3w^2}$

Comment: Sorry about that, I only realized after I finished the answer. I'll add in the LaTex formatting to make it clear.